# Overwatch 2 Tech Beta doesn't appear in Game Versions

Tags: battle.net, overwatch-2

I followed the instructions on Overwatch 2 open beta access.

- [A short official version](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/news/23798985/welcome-to-the-first-overwatch-2-pvp-beta/)
- [Detailed unofficial version](https://www.cnet.com/tech/gaming/how-to-get-overwatch-2-beta-access-from-twitch-drops-today/)

I have the drop earned and claimed on my twitch account:

[image]

But on the battle.net account, which is connected to my twitch account there is no other game version but standard "Overwatch"

[image]

I tried to restart the battle net launcher and to log out 3 times already - doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved on it's own. Looks like some delay on the battle.net part. Just had to wait, even restarting the launcher was not necessary.

Comment: They announced that if your accounts were linked prior then there was a 30 minutes or so delay on getting access to slow the pace down. If accounts weren't linked they were saying delays could take longer. I know it took about 12+ hours for it to show up for me after getting access, but some had it in that 30 minute window that I know